# Using Gedit for Prolog Development

Tags: prolog, gedit

I'm trying to set up the external tools plugin in Gedit, so that I can hit a button and have a prolog interpreter appear in the bottom pane. The problem I'm having is that the interpreter immediately closes. How can I have the interpreter not terminate as soon as it opens?

Comment: Which Prolog interpreter are you using?

Comment: What command do you use to define the external tool for SWI-Prolog?  What happens if you simplify things to just "swipl" as a command?  If your Prolog code contains a **prolog/0** predicate, what may be happening is that by default swipl interprets that as the goal to execute and then exits.  If this is so, I can give two or three ways to prevent that.

Comment: If I type prolog, or swipl in a regular terminal, I am presented with a prolog shell. If I create a command in external tools to do the same, the shell appears, and then immediately terminates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install gedit-plugins, they include a terminal that can be run on the bottom pane of gedit. You can start Prolog in it as normal.

http://live.gnome.org/GeditPlugins

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this interesting question.  I had a gedit window open, working away on a short Prolog program, when I saw your post.  You've inspired me to make it work!

Apparently the idea is to use a command `gnome-terminal` in the bash script to make a terminal session that supports regular user interaction.  See the discussion here:

[Gedit External Tools Problem [Solved] -- Ubuntu Forums]
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=936852

I'll give it a try myself...

Comment: That isn't exactly what I was thinking of.
I'm hoping to have the output in a pane at the bottom of GEdit.
Also I'm not having an issue with spaces, the issue I have is that the prolog interpreter halts as soon as it opens.

Comment: Okay, you want to get just the output of the SWI-Prolog run in the bottom pane?  I thought you wanted to run your program at "toplevel", i.e. interactively.  [I realize the spaces in filenames are irrelevant to your question, but the note linked shows how to pass the filename being edited as the argument to a commandline program (octave, rather than swipl).]  From what I've been reading that bottom pane is not a full terminal (doesn't support standard i/o), and is just an output target for a bash (or other) script.

Comment: @Varun Madiath:  Oops, forgot to direct the above comment back to you.

Comment: this now makes sense. If it's not a terminal, and can't accept stdio, then I can't run swipl in it. I'll have to look into maybe extending the external tools plugin to allow for that support.

Comment: @Varun Madiath:  I'll do some more testing and report findings. Here's an archived mail list message, External tools - no stdio interaction, that put me onto the analysis above. http://osdir.com/ml/gedit-list/2009-12/msg00020.html